# Sample rate issue arising on usage of Divide block in XSG

Tags: xilinx-system-generator

I'm trying to implement a Phase-locked loop using XSG in Simulink interface.

To calculate the angle from the output of the integrator, the integrator output is divided by 360, from which the fractional part is removed using a slice block. The sin(angle) is fed back to the input.

As the Divide block introduces a delay of around 20-24 cycles, the system sample rate is collapsing.  Using the Assert block as suggested also doesn't work. Tried the Up-sample block as well, yet there is a sample rate error.

The attached image could give an idea of the error.
[image: Sample rate error]

Please help!

Edit : Enhanced PLL

[image: Enhanced PLL]

The output of the integrator gives angle phi. The angle phi is required to be within the range 0-360 in order to compute sin(phi) and cos(phi), using look up table (ROM). I'm trying to find the modulus or remainder of division by 360 to get phi withing the required range.

Comment: I've never seen a PLL that used a divider. The way I would mathematically formulate a PLL wouldn't use one, either. So, I'm not sure why you even have a divider in there? Can you write down the math of what you're implementing there?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Enhanced PLL method in FPGA. I've edited my question to include the image of the same, as I'm unable to paste it here. The output of the integrator gives angle phi. The angle phi is required to be within the range 0-360 in order to compute sin(phi) and cos(phi), using look up table (ROM). I'm trying to find the modulus or remainder of division by 360 to get phi withing the required range.

Comment: there's no ROM on an FPGA, but there's look up tables ;-) but thanks for adding the figure. Yes, this helps. I don't see a division in that figure. Are we maybe talking about *decimation* of a sample stream, not *division*?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time mapping the diagram below to the diagram above. Did you make a drawing of how to time-discretize the lower diagram before implementing it? If not, now would be a good time! make sure to insert delay blocks where necessary.

Comment: In the figure, the integrator constants are discretized using the sampling time. The integrator itself is implemented as i[n-1]=i[n]. Delay blocks are used.the output of the last integrator gives

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller Used the Assert block with Rate equal to input sampling time, and it worked. Thanks.